# Compile Haskell "direct-fastcgi" package with stack

Tags: haskell, ghc

I tried to compile Haskell [direct-fastcgi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/direct-fastcgi) package with stack (setup-Simple-Cabal-1.18.1.5-ghc-7.8.4) and got follow errors (see below).

Is it a compatibility issues with GHC 7.8.4? Could somebody advice me how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

---

```
Configuring direct-fastcgi-1.0.3...
Building direct-fastcgi-1.0.3...
Preprocessing library direct-fastcgi-1.0.3...
[1 of 1] Compiling Network.FastCGI  ( Network/FastCGI.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Network/FastCGI.o )    

Network/FastCGI.hs:248:16:
    Not in scope: ‘Exception.block’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      data constructor ‘Exception.Deadlock’ (imported from Control.Exception),
      ‘Exception.catch’ (imported from Control.Exception),
      ‘Exception.bracket’ (imported from Control.Exception)    
Network/FastCGI.hs:251:16:
    Not in scope: ‘Exception.unblock’
    Perhaps you meant data constructor ‘Exception.Deadlock’ (imported from Control.Exception)    
Network/FastCGI.hs:368:3: Not in scope: ‘System.catch’    
Network/FastCGI.hs:389:3: Not in scope: ‘System.catch’
```

---

### stack.yaml:

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- direct-fastcgi-1.0.3
- utf8-string-0.3.8
resolver: lts-6.13
```

Comment: what is the resolver you are using ? Is there a stack.yaml file associated ? Can you share it with us ?

Comment: `Control.Exception.block` has been deprecated for a long time and was [removed by GHC 7.8.4](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Exception.html). This package is simply extremely outdated (5 yr!!) - either update it yourself or revert back to an older GHC (fortunately, stack makes the latter extremely easy for you). Or, of course, use a package which is properly maintained.